# echo do_shortcode is not working on theme's template

Tags: plugins, shortcode, errors, jwplayer

I don't know whats causing the problem but the `echo do_shortcode` is not working on my theme's template, but its working on my plugin's template and the shortcode  is working on my posts and pages. Pretty weird. Here's the code

```
<?php 
$my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=video post&posts_per_page=10');
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; 
?>

    <li>
    <h3><a href = "<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h3>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>                          
    <p> 
    <?php the_excerpt();?>
    <?php                                       
    $urlbox = get_video_box();

    echo $urlbox[0]; // echo out the url of a post                     
    echo $urlbox[1]; // echo out the url description of a post
    echo do_shortcode('[jwplayer config="Out-of-the-Box" file="' . $urlbox[0] . '" image="http://www.mywebsite.com/myimage.jpg"]');
    ?>          

    </p>
    </li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I am using the JW player plugin, again, the shortcode is working on the plugin's template and post/page . but on my theme's template its not working.. please help me here. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a link to your website? It's possible that there could be conflicting scripts on that particular page.

Comment: Has the hook with which you add the shortcode run when the theme template is loaded?

Comment: I don't know how but after deactivating and reactivating plugins, the code is now working. Anyway, Thanks Guys. :)

Comment: I have the same issue with do_shortcode() and jwPlayer in my theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the developer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/20472/wordpress-doshortcode-not-working) of the jwPlayer it was necessary to implement the plugin as a filter to be able to support '.' in tag attributes. Hence `do_shortcode(..)` does not work but `jwplayer_tag_callback(..)` will return the desired result.

Matching your example simply execute:

```
echo jwplayer_tag_callback('[jwplayer config="Out-of-the-Box" file="' . $urlbox[0] . '" image="http://www.mywebsite.com/myimage.jpg"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

### Update for everyone visiting this thread (2015)

`jwplayer_tag_callback()` does not work anymore, you'll get a fatal error telling you the function is not defined.

Instead insert a player programmatically like this:

```
echo JWP6_Shortcode::the_content_filter( '[jwplayer file="'. $videoUrl .'"]' );
```

(Found [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/jwplayer_tag_callback-fatal-error#post-6162126).)